# Different tracked data on domain.com and domain.ca needed

Tags: google-analytics

I have a customer who wants data tracked independently from his 2 website that are almost the same. The international one: .com, and the Canadian one: .ca .

I have made a JS script that detects if the page is .com or is .ca and create the tracker's function depending on it.

I can't find any infos on how to do this. I am not even sure if this method would work.

There is probably a better way to do this

script:

```
var pageUrl = document.URL;
var pageUrlArray = pageUrl.split('.');
var GA = "<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', '";
if (pageUrlArray.indexOf('.ca') != -1) { //Website is .ca
    GA += "UA-xxxxxxxx-1";
} else { //Website is .com
    GA += "UA-xxxxxxxx-2";
}
GA += "', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');<\/script>";
document.getElementById('checkForGood').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', GA);
```

Will this work? Will my data be tracked separately on my 2 different views in GooglaAnalytics? If not, what should I do ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Will this work? Will my data be tracked separately on my 2 different views in GooglaAnalytics? If not, what should I do ?